# Generating search links using text input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a website which makes searches easy for me.
I want to be able to write any text in a text box, and make a java script generate the appropriate links.

Ive been trying this:

```
function prepare_link() {
    var url_param = document.getElementById('url_param');
    var target_link = document.getElementById('target_link');
    if ( ! url_param.value ) {
        return false;  
    }
    target_link.href = target_link.href + escape(url_param.value);
}
```

```
<input type="text" name="url_param" id="url_param" onkeypress='prepare_link()' onKeyUp='prepare_link()' />
<input type="button" onclick="prepare_link();" value="Generate" /><br>
<a href="https://www.google.dk/search?q=" id="target_link">Google</a><br>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" id="Youtube">Bing</a>
```

For some reason the search string is repeated, but i would like it to update links for each keypress and not just when i hit the generate button.
Moreover the second links isn't being updated :(

Any ideas? :)

Comment: _The second links isnt begin updated_. That is because your function only handles the first link.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look of the following code snippet, hope this will help to resolve your Issue.
In the following snippet you will not get the repeated values. Also, it will work with 'keyup' and 'click' event :

```
var google = "https://www.google.dk/search?q=";

function prepare_link() {

    var target_link = document.getElementById('target_link');
    target_link.href = google + escape(url_param.value);
    alert(target_link.href);  
}

void function () {
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  prepare_link();
  e.preventDefault();
});

var click = document.getElementById("target_link");
click.addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
});
```

}();

```
<input type="text" name="url_param" id="url_param" value=""/>
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="prepare_link();" /><br>
<a href="javascript:google" id="target_link">Google</a><br>
```

Thanks :)